# Elastic Search results did not search space between words

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch-rails gem in my rails application. Everything is setup, but i am having trouble when i search two words with space between them. 
Here is my code:

```
SEARCH_FIELDS = %w"name email"
attribute :text, type: String, default: ''

response = MyModelName.search([query, filter, sort].compact.reduce(:merge)).page(page).per(per_page)
  def query
    query = {}.tap do |q|
      q[:query_string] = {query: text, default_operator: 'AND', fields: SEARCH_FIELDS, allow_leading_wildcard: true}
    end
    return {query: query}
  end

  def filter
    filters = []
    filters << {term: {user_id: user_id}}
    filters << {term: {hide: (hide.nil? ? false : hide)}}
    return {filter: {and: filters}}
  end
```

If i search first initials of name like ('John') that works fine, but name with space('John doe') did not get found.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you're building the right syntax for your query, is you want exact match in ES you must set query between qoutes

search_field:"daniel acevedo"

```
   {          
      "size": 10,
      "query": {
        "query_string": {
          "query": "search_field:\"daniel acevedo\""

        }
      }
    }
```